# Method some_method() always returns false

Tags: php, pdo

I have following two classes called *One* and *Two* respectively. Class One has database stuff in it. Where method `connect()` returns a variable (a property) that is the *database handler* (`$dbh`). I have used `connect()` literally hundreds of times and it works as anticipated. Here too, (in method `query()`) it should work correctly. Now the work the method `query()` has to do is to prepare a statement (`$query` in this case) and execute it, after which it fetches data as an associative array and returns the data. I call this method in multiple methods, and works fine in all except in the method `some_method()` in class Two.

```
class One {
  protected function query($sql, $params=[]){
    $query = $this->connect()->prepare($sql); // Method connect() returns database handler ($dbh)
    $query->execute($params);
    $storage = $query->fetch(); // Fetch as an associative array
    return $storage;
  }
}
```

Now here in `some_method()` in class Two, method `query()`(from class One), is called where a variable `$sql` and also an associative array `$params` are declared as shown in the code below. All this method has to do is to call the method `query()`, with the parameters `$sql` and `$params`, and store the result in `$storage`. If `$storage==false`, `return false` and if `$storage` has some value other than `false`, `return true`. And this result (i.e., true or false) depends on if the database has an entry in the column *class_date* as specified in `$params['date']`. Now here comes the problem, irrespective of if the database has that value in that column, the method `some_method()`, always returns false. I don't know what mistake I'm doing here. Can someone point it out please.

```
class Two extends class One{
  public function some_method($date){
    $sql = 'SELECT class_date FROM table_name WHERE id=:id AND class_date=:date';
    $params = [
      'id' => $this->user_id,
      'date' => $date
    ];
    $array = $this->query($sql, $params);
    return ($array==false) ? false : true;
  }
}
```

Comment: try return ($array)?true:false;

Comment: Are you sure you provided the correct date, provide us the format used (what is in `$date`) and make sure your date value in the database is actually a `DATE` and not a `DATETIME`, which can interfere with matching

Comment: @Hardood I tried but unfortunately that doesn't work. Thank you, btw

Comment: @YouriKoeman Even I was thinking the same, so I reformatted the `class_date` column from date to varchar. And now I use the same format to get input from the user and and to enter it into the database that is 09-May-2020. And I use very similar logic in another method like in `some_method()`, even there same thing happens.

Comment: can you provide the values  of `$date` , `$array`, `DB: class_date`with their types, it will help us help you.

Comment: also, i noticed you match the value of a variable called `user_id` to a database column called `id` are you sure you are quering against the correct columns?

Comment: Have you tried to var_dump( $array ) in some_method to see if it holds values or not?

Comment: @YouriKoeman $date is got as user input as a string '26-May-2020'. $array is declared as an empty array which gets the value after calling `query()` method. Finally `class_date` column in database is text type and stores dates in th format *09-May-2020*. And yes I'm have entered correct column names in the query.

Comment: @Hardood Yes I've tried `var_dump($array)`, and to my disappointment it is *bool(false)*.

Comment: Then the problem in your query, try to review the values of parameters especially the date param and try again.